# pypi cannot install behind proxy

Tags: python, pip, pyramid, pypi

Whether I use PIP or download manually and run 'python setup.py install' on Pyramid I'm getting the same error: accessing standard pypi websites.

If I visit the sites in my browser it all works, but if I run the command it doesn't. Error as below.

I guess the fault will occur on most packages using these url's because I'm behind a proxy and my proxy is disallowing web access via python executable?

How do I specify pip or simply the apps setup.py to use my proxy, assuming this is the problem.

```
Installed c:\pymon\python34\lib\site-packages\pyramid-1.5.1-py3.4.egg
Processing dependencies for pyramid==1.5.1
Searching for PasteDeploy>=1.5.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/PasteDeploy/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/PasteDeploy/: timed out -- Some
packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'PasteDeploy' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for PasteDeploy>=1.5.0
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PasteDeploy>=
```

1.5.0')

Comment: You can specify proxy parameter for pip. `pip install package --proxy=http://username:password@server:port`

Answer (score 2):

My apologies I should have searched further:
[Plone: pypi specific download issue behind a proxy server - can't install eggs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488508/plone-pypi-specific-download-issue-behind-a-proxy-server-cant-install-eggs)

I created two environment variables: HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY

Note the above comment regarding the --proxy argument also worked via pip.